# C++ If/Else loop problems

Tags: c++, if-statement

Checking user input. If the incorrect input is entered, it loops fine. If the correct input is entered, It has 2 be entered again in order for it to register. Help?

```
int deposit;

cout << "How much do you want to deposit?" << endl;
cin >> deposit;

if (!(cin >> deposit)) { // If the input is not equal to the data type of
                         // deposit
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;

} else {
  while (infile >> u >> p >> b) {
    if (checkUser == u) {
      int newBalance;
      cout << "Your amount of $" << deposit << " has been added to your account"
           << endl;
      int fileBalance;
      stringstream convert(b); // object from the class stringstream
      convert >> fileBalance;  // the objects has the value of B and
      newBalance = fileBalance + deposit;
      outfile << checkUser << ' ' << checkPass << ' ' << newBalance << endl;
    } else {
      outfile << u << ' ' << p << ' ' << b << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling cin>>deposit twice, so you would expect that two numbers are need to be entered. Also, the else block doesn't have a closing bracket.

Comment: @Holget Schmitz Thanks! Newbie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering input twice because you go through `cin>>deposit` at least twice:

```
cout << "How much do you want to deposit?" << endl;
cin >> deposit;

if (!(cin >> deposit)) {
```

Just get rid of the first `cin`:

```
cout << "How much do you want to deposit?" << endl;
if (!(cin >> deposit)) {
```

Also, have a look at setting up `clang-format` with your code editor or IDE. It makes your code look nice without effort and will help you spot errors. There's also an online version available here: http://format.krzaq.cc/

Answer (score 0):

It's because here:

> if(!(cin>>deposit))

you're re-reading from standard input. When you first do  `cin>>deposit`, you've already stored the value in the variable, so you just have to check the `deposit` variable, or whatever you want to do with the inserted data.

Another, cleaner, way of doing it is to just avoid the first `cin>>deposit` statement.